# How can I put RavenDB and associated data access in its own Project?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ravendb

I want to use RavenDB for my personal blog project built on ASP.NET MVC3.

I like to have multiple projects in my solution, so I would have one web project and another class library as the blog engine using RavenDB as its datastore that the web project would call.

How should I setup RavenDB so I can use it from a class library?

Answer (score 0):

One option you might consider is using Inversion of Control / Dependency Injection to create an instance of DocumentStore as a singleton and inject it into your services via the constructor.  I'm using Munq, so my example will use that, but there are lots of other IOC frameworks out there to consider.

```
// In your Global.asax Application_Start
// MUNQ.  This will give you a RavenDB IDocumentStore as Singleton
var ioc = MunqDependencyResolver.Container;
ioc.Register<IDocumentStore>(c => InitializeRaven()).WithLifetimeManager(new ContainerLifetime());

// Initialize yourself some RavenDB
public static IDocumentStore InitializeRaven()
{
    DocumentStore instance = new DocumentStore { Url = "http://localhost:8080/" };
    instance.Initialize();
    return instance;
}
```

This will get you a single instance of DocumentStore to use throughout the lifetime of your application.

Here's a Stack Overflow question that may give your some additional guidance (Autofac):

[ASP.NET MVC 3, RavenDB, & Autofac Issue Plus 2 Other Autofac Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5516601/asp-net-mvc-3-ravendb-autofac-issue-plus-2-other-autofac-questions)

And an example of MSNBC using it (Ninject):

http://development.msnbc.msn.com/_news/2011/08/19/7419461-ninjectmvc3-dependency-injection-in-30-seconds-or-less?lite

Answer (score -1):

Did you read some [tutorials/documentation](http://ravendb.net/docs/intro) about RavenDB? You create a `DocumentStore` that will allow you to connect and query the database:

```
public IEnumerable<Company> GetCompanies()
{
    using (var dc = new DocumentStore("localhost", 8080).Initialize())
    using (var session = dc.OpenSession())
    {
        return session
            .Query<Company>("regionIndex")
            .Where("Region:Europe")
            .ToArray();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a HORRIBLE use of the API, since it create a different DocumentStore for each opeartion, and micro manages the session

Comment: Would be grateful if you showed the correct usage as an author of this framework.