# How can I register this .NET interface with AutoFac?

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, autofac

I've trying to do the following with AutoFac (samples taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5516601/asp-net-mvc-3-ravendb-autofac-issue-plus-2-other-autofac-questions) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13279942/register-ravendb-using-autofac)):

```
builder.Register(c => c.Resolve<IDocumentStore>().OpenSession())          
       .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

problem is, with the current release of AutoFac, i get a compile error with `c.Resolve`

Can someone please tell me how I can register an `IDocumentSession`, which is given to me by an `IDocumentStore` instance `OpenSession()` method.

[image]

Comment: that issue is to do with R#, delete your R# cache and re-open the solution. If you ever come across that problem, and the project builds fine but you get warnings regardless, R# issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
builder.RegisterInstance(documentStore).As<IDocumentStore>();

builder.Register(x => x.Resolve<IDocumentStore>().OpenSession())
       .As<IDocumentSession>()
       .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```